# how to compare mobile number with country code and without country code in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to compare mobile number in php

For example,

first number is 9999999999
and
second number is +919999999999

now how to match this 2 number is equal or not.

Comment: They're not. Unless you have more information available that you are not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming *all* mobile numbers are 10-digit (so far I haven't come across any that aren't), won't it be easier to just compare the last 10 characters of the two string?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-compare.php

Comment: Mobile number length is unique for all country?

Comment: No. Hence the assumption. Try http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/181772/mobile-number-validation

Answer (score 0):

you can use the preg_replace function to replace the initial +99 with either 0099 as international preselection or 0 as national preselection
Then compare this towards the mobile number.

```
$pattern='|(\+)((\d{2})(\d+))|';
//comment that $replace, you don't want to use
$replace='00$3$4'; //replaces initial +49 with 0049 (international pre selection)
$replace='0$4'; //replaces initial +49 with 0 (national pre selection)
$tel="+49163 1234567";
$tel_clean=preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$tel);
```

regards

Comment: for clarification: the regex takes the first two digits after the plus sign. +49 is just in this example. When you feed a +999999999 the function will replace the +99.